# How to turn day number to a word (letters) with ireport?

Tags: php, date, jasper-reports

I'm currently working in iReport 5.50 creating a formal document. Right at the end of it must be a line like the following: "(...) This document is extended on the seventh of July of Two Thousand Fourteen".

The part "seventh of July of Two Thusand Fourteen" is the current day. I wish to know if there's a way of getting the current date displayed in words just like the document needs it to be. So far, I only know how to obtain Name of the day of the week and the Name of the month...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should post some of your code. Why is this tagged java **and** php??

Comment: I'm working on ireport and not using any personal code since the document isn't so hard to shape (except for this little problem). I tagged php because I'm going to incorporate this report in a php app (sorry for not specifying more).

Answer (score 0):

Although what you want is related to dates, it is a quite general problem.

What you want is to convert a number to its [ordinal equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)), which is a classic programming exercise.

Here's some example PHP code (I've fixed some issues in the original):

```
function numToOrdinalWord($num)
{
    $first_word = array('eth', 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth',
         'Seventh', 'Eighth', 'Ninth', 'Tenth', 'Eleventh', 'Twelfth', 'Thirteenth',
         'Fourteenth', 'Fifteenth', 'Sixteenth', 'Seventeenth', 'Eighteenth',
         'Nineteenth', 'Twentieth');
    $second_word = array('', '', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety');

    if ($num <= 20) return ($num == 0) ? 'Zeroth' : $first_word[$num];

    $first_num = substr($num, -1, 1);
    $second_num = substr($num, -2, 1);

    return $string = str_replace(
        'y-eth',
        'ieth',
        $second_word[$second_num] . '-' . $first_word[$first_num]
    );
}
```

[Live Demo](http://3v4l.org/e8jRo) | [Original Source](http://webdeveloperblog.tiredmachine.com/php-converting-an-integer-123-to-ordinal-word-firstsecondthird/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it out and then come back with the results.